# Display Pound currency sign (£) in a DataBound DropDownListItem

Tags: asp.net, webforms, drop-down-menu, special-characters

I need to show items like in below image.

[image]

I'm using this code to bind dropdownlist.

```
var options = (from option in _serviceOptions
                select new
                {
                  OptionId = option.OptionId,
                  OptionText = option.OptionText + " - " + option.Price + "&pound;/month"

                }).ToList();

myDdl.DataSource = options;
myDdl.DataValueField = "OptionId";
myDdl.DataTextField = "OptionText";
myDdl.DataBind();
```

`_serviceOptions` is the resultset returned by calling stored procedure using L2S

The problem is, it is again encoding the `&` to `&amp;` before rendering to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the pound sign £ instead of `&pound;`. It works here. The £ will be converted to `&#163;` which is equal to `&pound;`.

```
var options = (from option in _serviceOptions
                select new
                {
                  OptionId = option.OptionId,
                  OptionText = option.OptionText + " - " + option.Price + "£/month"

                }).ToList();
```

Comment: How do I type pound character in Visual Studio?

Comment: Copy the sign or code from my post :) or in unicode like: "\u00a3"